# Will $Q_{in}$ increase in this case?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

When increasing boiler pressure in rankine cycle the efficiency increases, I think this is because $Q_{in}=(\triangle S).(T_{avg})$ and $T_{avg}$ will increase when the boiler pressure increase and So $Q_{in}$ with no change To $Q_{out}$ so $n^{th}=Q_{in}-Q_{out}$ / Qin increase. Am I true?

Comment: By $n^{th}$ do you mean $W_{T}+W_P$ where $W_T$ is turbine work and $W_P$ is pump work?

Comment: Yes,  But  it is actually work turbine - work pump

Comment: It is algebraically turbine work plus pump work, but pump work is negative because it is done on the fluid whereas turbine work is positive because it done by the fluid. Alternatively, it is the magnitude of the turbine work minus the magnitude of the pump work. In any case, why did you use $n^{th}$?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I true?

Essentially, yes.

It follows that if you increase the temperature at which heat is added, all else being the same, you theoretically increase the efficiency. Since the heat addition in the reversible Rankine cycle is not isothermal, you need to use the mean (average) temperature at which heat is added.

In the case where the output of the boiler (input to the turbine) is saturated vapor and the temperature $T_L$ at which heat is rejected can be considered approximately constant and equal to the condenser temperature, the Rankine efficiency can be approximated as

$$\eta_{R}=\frac{Q_{IN}-Q_{OUT}}{Q_{IN}}=\frac{T_{Hm}\Delta S-T_{L}\Delta S}{T_{Hm}\Delta S}=1-\frac{T_L}{T_{Hm}}$$

Where $T_{Hm}$ is the mean temperature at which heat is added and $T_H$ is the maximum boiler temperature.

Given that the Carnot efficiency is

$$\eta_{C}=1-\frac{T_L}{T_H}$$

And that for the Rankine cycle the mean temperature is less than the maximum temperature, or $T_{Hm}<T_H$, we have

$$\eta_{R}<\eta_{C}$$

It also follows that if you increase $T_H$ by outputting superheated steam from the boiler instead of saturated vapor, $T_{Hm}$ will also increase, improving the efficiency of the Rankine cycle.

Hope this helps.